# Reading contract balances with Waffle?

Tags: unit-testing, solidity, smartcontracts

### Context

After adopting a waffle example I'm experiencing some difficulties in reading out the balances of the contracts that are made using a unit test in Waffle.

### Test file

```
import {expect, use} from 'chai';
import {Contract, utils, Wallet} from 'ethers';
import {deployContract, deployMockContract, MockProvider, solidity} from 'ethereum-waffle';

import IERC20 from '../build/IERC20.json';
import AmIRichAlready from '../build/AmIRichAlready.json';
import SolveContract from '../build/SolveContract.json';
import RandomNumberConsumer from '../build/RandomNumberConsumer.json';

use(solidity);

describe('Am I Rich Already', () => {
    // Declare contracts
    let mockERC20: Contract;
    let askRootContract: Contract;
    let solveRootContract: Contract;
    let vrfContract: Contract;
    
    // Declare wallets
    let mockWallet: Wallet;
    let askRootWallet: Wallet;
    let solveRootWallet: Wallet;
    let vrfWallet: Wallet;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        
        // generate random wallets or random origin 
        //const [mockWallet, askRootWallet, solveRootWallet, vrfWallet] = Wallet.createRandom();
        //const original = Wallet.createRandom();
        
        // specify wallet balances
        const provider = new MockProvider(
            {
                ganacheOptions: {
                    // The private key is used to generate the four respective wallet addresses.
                    accounts: [
                        {balance: '16862680000000000001', secretKey: '0x706618637b8ca922f6290ce1ecd4c31247e9ab75cf0530a0ac95c0332173d7c1'}, 
                        {balance: '16862680000000000002', secretKey: '0x706618637b8ca922f6290ce1ecd4c31247e9ab75cf0530a0ac95c0332173d7c2'}, 
                        {balance: '16862680000000000003', secretKey: '0x706618637b8ca922f6290ce1ecd4c31247e9ab75cf0530a0ac95c0332173d7c3'},
                        {balance: '16862680000000000004', secretKey: '0x706618637b8ca922f6290ce1ecd4c31247e9ab75cf0530a0ac95c0332173d7c4'}
                    ]
                }
            }
        );
        
        [mockWallet, askRootWallet, solveRootWallet, vrfWallet] = provider.getWallets();
        mockERC20 = await deployMockContract(mockWallet, IERC20.abi);
        askRootContract = await deployContract(askRootWallet, AmIRichAlready, [mockERC20.address]);
        solveRootContract = await deployContract(solveRootWallet, SolveContract, [mockERC20.address]);
        vrfContract = await deployContract(vrfWallet, RandomNumberConsumer);
    });

    // custom test in AskRoot contract
    it('checks askRootContract address is returned correctly', async () => {
        expect(await askRootContract.getAddressThis()).to.be.equal('0x82A666453d8aa239eEBE4578E83cD0988D62c83F');
    });
    
    // custom test in AskRoot contract
    it('checks askRootWallet address balance is returned correctly', async () => {
        expect(await askRootContract.getAddressThisBalance()).to.be.equal(9001);
    }); 
});
```

### Example contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.9.0;

// Example contract of a TestContract.
contract SolveContract {
    
    bool forTestingPurposes;    // Boolean to run test on this contract
    
    TemplateTestContract testContract;  // Create variable for the testContract which needs to be solved.
    address payable owner;              // Create variable for the owner which solves the test contract.

    // Constructor to initialise the contract variables.
    constructor(address testAddress) public payable {
        testContract = TemplateTestContract(testAddress);   // Initialise the testContract variable.
        owner = msg.sender;                                 // Initialise the owner of the contract to be the creator of the contract.
    }
    
    // Function to solve the testContract.
    function solve() public payable returns(uint256){
        testContract.differentFunctionName(owner);
        return owner.balance;
    }

    // Example of the main function which solves the testContract.
    // Calculates the squre root function.
    function main(uint x) pure public returns(uint y) {
        uint z = (x + 1) / 2;
        y = x;
        while (z < y) {
            y = z;
            z = (x / z + z) / 2;
        }
    }
    
    
    // Getter function for the Ownership.
    function getOwner() public view returns (address) { 
        return owner;
    }
    
    // Getter function for the address(this).
    function getAddressThis() public view returns (address) { 
        return address(this);
    }
    
    // Getter function for the balance of the contract.
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        //return address(this).balance;
        //testAddress.balance;
        return owner.balance;
    }
    
    // Getter function for the forTestingPurposes boolean.
    function getForTestingPurposes() public view returns (bool){   
        return forTestingPurposes;
    }
    
}

// TemplateTestContract so the SolveContract knows the structure of the testContract.
abstract contract TemplateTestContract {
    function differentFunctionName(address payable hunter) public virtual;
}
```

### Test Output

```
1) checks askRootWallet address balance is returned correctly
     AssertionError: Expected "0" to be equal 9001
      at Context.it (test/AmIRichAlready.test.ts:53:76)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

### Question

How can I (set) and read out the balance of the wallet address of a particular contract in a Waffle test?

Answer (score 1):

Your test script is calling function `getAddressThisBalance()`, but this function is not defined in the contract.

Different JSON-RPC wrappers act differently when performing calls (read-only, without transaction) to non-existing contract functions. Some return `undefined`, some throw an exception, and it seems that Waffle returns a value that can be typecasted to `0`.

**Solution:**

1. Unify the contract function `getBalance()` and the JS snippet calling `getAddressThisBalance()`. E.g. change the JS call to `getBalance()`.
2. Uncomment the line `return address(this).balance;` in your `getBalance()` contract function. This expression returns the current balance of the contract.